# How to get row count based on the column?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

*Consider,

```
int arr[][]={{1,2,3,4},
             {5,6,7,8},
             {9,10,11}};
```

In arr, 0th column have 3 rows,
similarly,1st and 2nd column also have 3 rows.
But 3rd column(last column) only have 2 rows.
How to get the row count on column basis?*

Comment: Iterate over each rows, check their length, count those with length greater than column index.

Answer (score 0):

below code demonstrates the size

```
// arr.length gives the number of rows    

for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  // arr[i].length  is the size of row  (columns in row)
  for(int j=0; j<arr[i].length; j++){
    // arr[i][j] points to each item in array
  }
}
```